# How do I put a parentheses in text?

Tags: brackets, parenthesis

I just want to use the ")" symbol without closing the parentheses. I don't really want to use math mode, can I just put it in the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX has brackets in text mode too. This

```
Blah )
```

will compile as well as

```
Blah $)$
```

Comment: A small sample document showing this working would improve the answer.  Note that in some set-ups you will get different brackets from the two approaches.

Comment: I guess I should've just tried it. I was using TexStudio and it shows a visual clue like an error, even within text. It still compiles like you said however.

Comment: @DanielGuenther Don't always trust what TeXstudio says. Most times unmatched brackets are not what you want, and where it used to specifiy for example coordinates in diagrams you'll get errors even from unmatched parens. However, TeXstudio cannot guess that you want just a closing parenthesis, so it warns you about it anyway.